# JSoup couldn't parse tr tag

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse String value to JSoup Document as follows:

```java
    String value = "<tr> <td>Value</td>> </tr>";
    Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.parse(parseTrxRawToHtml);
    System.out.println(htmlDoc.html());
```

the result after code has been executed :

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>    
 </body>
</html>
```

But, it seems JSoup couldn't parsed any `<tr>` tag inside my String value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to manipulate partial HTML pages using JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473677/is-there-a-way-to-manipulate-partial-html-pages-using-jsoup)

Comment: no it's different context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently JSoup couldn't parse `<tr>` tag directly without `<table>` tag outside `<tr>` tag.
So, i added `<table>` tag to the value like below and it solves the problem:

```java
    String value = "<table> <tr> <td>Value</td> </tr> </table>"
```

Comment: are you aware you've got `>>` at the end of the closing `td` tag?

Comment: oh my bad. it's just typo